# HW0002 Tera Scanner comport to Keyboard Wedge

Tags: com-port, keyboard-wedge

I have a Tera HW002 hand scanner which I am trying to get to change from a comport to keyboard Wedge but nothing appears to be working, reading through the manual mentions about changing to com port but not from com port

I have so far tried;
resetting the scanner to factory settings,
uninstalling the comport,
reinstalling the drivers for the hand scanners

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more information, such as version info, links to the manual mentioned and more specifics on what you tried, what you expected, and what results you got instead